# Elasticsearch array field is sorted when accessed within Painless scripting language

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

I have an integer array field, for example, `my_integer_array`.

I stored `[3, 4, 1, 2]` on the field via client and I can see that `[3, 4, 1, 2]` is successfully set on the document's `my_integer_array` field via Kibana.

But whenever I try to access the field in Painless Elasticsearch scripting language, e.g. `doc['my_integer_array']`, it returns `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, not `[3, 4, 1, 2]`. Accessing it's element via `doc['my_integer_array'][0]`  returns `1`, not `3`.

It seems like Painless provides sorted version of the field's data rather than the original array itself. Am I missing something? Can I disable this behavior and preserve the order?

P.S. I'm using [elasticsearch-dsl-py](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py) Elasticsearch Python DSL library as an Elasticsearch client.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @ZaidAmir No. I failed to solve this issue.

Comment: I think this so answer can give you some insights => https://stackoverflow.com/a/43836510/2119685

Answer (score 1):

You can access the array setting _source:true and then using params._source['my_integer_array'] this way the array will be unsorted in its original state.